# Print FormatList Issue

Tags: python, list, printing, format

I'm just having a small issue of formatting right now. My current code prints out my out in a wonky way and I'm trying to make it look smoother. How would I change my print formatting?

```
height = {}

length = len(preys)
rank = 0
while preys != [None]*length:
    for index,(animal,prey) in enumerate(zip(animals,preys)):
        if prey not in animals:
            try:
                if height[prey] < rank:
                    height[prey] = rank
            except KeyError:
                height[prey] = 0

            height[animal] = height[prey] + 1

            preys[index] = None
            animals[index] = None
    rank += 1
for arg in sys.argv:
    print (sorted (height.items(),key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True))
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    main()

---

The output looks like this:

[('Lobster', 4), ('Bird', 4), ('Fish', 3), ('Whelk', 3), ('Crab', 3), ('Mussels', 2), ('Prawn', 2), ('Zooplankton', 1), ('Limpets', 1), ('Phytoplankton', 0), ('Seaweed', 0)]

and I'm trying to make it look like:

```
Heights:
Bird: 4
Crab: 3
Fish: 3
Limpets: 1
Lobster: 4
Mussels: 2
Phytoplankton: 0
Prawn: 2
Seaweed: 0
Whelk: 3
Zooplankton: 1
```

I've attempted to use the: print(formatList(height)), format however printing anything before the "height" causes errors

Comment: Why are you looping over `sys.argv` and then not doing anything with it? Where is `main`? I suppose there's `import sys` somewhere? Your question would be more clear if you provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Since the output only prints once, we know that `sys.argv` wasn't passed any extra arguments. There's no need to create a loop that will only be executed once (and, if there were multiple arguments, it isn't generally useful to print the same output several times). Instead, loop over the `height` object itself.

You are also currently sorting by value, when it's obvious that you want to sort by key. Since the latter is the default sort anyway, I'm not sure why you added (messy) code to sort by value.

Use string formatting to express the appearance you want for each item.

```
print('Heights:')
for item in sorted(height.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(*item))
```

Note that sorting an iterable of `tuple` objects will sort by the first element first, and then, if there are two `tuple`s with the same first item, they will be sorted by the second element. For example, `('Bird', 1)` would come before `('Bird', 2)`. Since dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, this won't be an issue here, but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try something like this:

```
sorted_ list = sorted (height.items(),key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
print(''.join('%s : %s\n' % x for x in sorted_list))
```

Or in one expression(if it is not ugly for you):

```
print(''.join('%s : %s\n' % x 
              for x in sorted (height.items(),key = lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output.